# MIPS program, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

Hello I have a MIPS program that tries to accomplish the following image.

[image]

```
.text #begin code text segment
.globl main #program entry point
main:
        la $a0, prompt1     #load prompt1
    li $v0, 4       #syscall code for print string
    syscall         #print string  print prompt.

    li $v0, 5           #syscall code to read integer
    syscall         #read integer into $v0
    move $t1, $v0

    la $a0, prompt2         #load prompt2
    li $v0, 4       #syscall code for print string
    syscall         #print string  print prompt.

    li $v0, 5           #syscall code to read integer
    syscall         #read integer into $v0
    move $t2, $v0

    la $a0, prompt3         #load prompt3
    li $v0, 4       #syscall code for print string
    syscall         #print string  print prompt.

    li $v0, 5           #syscall code to read integer
    syscall         #read integer into $v0
    move $t3, $v0


    add $t0, $t1, $t2   #t3 = t1 + t2
    add     $t0, $t3, $t0   #t3 = t3+ t0

    la  $a0, ans1       #load address for ans1 string to a0
    li  $v0, 4          #load print string code into v0
    syscall                 #print the ans1 string


    move    $a0, $t0            #(t0) -> a0
    li  $v0, 1              # load syscall code to print integer
    syscall             # display integer result of conversion
     la $a0, end1           #load address of end1 CR/LF code
    li  $v0,4               #load syscall code for string output
    syscall             #output CR/LF 

    j     findMin3

        la  $a0, loop       #load address for loop string to a0
    li  $v0, 4          #load print string code into v0
    syscall                 #print the ans1 string


    li $v0, 5           #syscall code to read integer
    syscall         #read integer into $v0
    move $t5, $v0

        la  $a0, end1           #load address of end1 CR/LF code
    li  $v0,4               #load syscall code for string output
    syscall             #output CR/LF 

        beq    $t5,0 ,main             #checks if the value is equal to 0
        li     $v0,10                  #ends the code 
        syscall 

           findMin3:
        move $t0,$t1              # min = x
             bge  $t2,$t0, IF_two     #branch  if  y < min
             move  $t0, $t2          #min = y
 IF_two:     bge  $t2, $t0, END   # branch if z<min
            move  $t0, $t3        #min = z
 END:      move  $v0, $t0    #retrieve val
            jr  $ra           #return

.data # begin the data segment

end1:.asciiz "\n"
prompt1:.asciiz "Enter the  first integer: "
end1:.asciiz "\n"
prompt2:.asciiz "Enter the second integer: "
end1:.asciiz "\n"
prompt3:.asciiz "Enter the third integer: "
end1:.asciiz "\n"
ans1:.asciiz "The sum of the three integers is is: "
end1:.asciiz "\n"
end1:.asciiz "\n"
loop:.asciiz "0 to start again "
end1:.asciiz "\n"
```

However, I get alot of erros when I run the program.

Assemble: assembling F:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Assign 3a - First Assembler Program
Assemble: operation completed successfully.

```
Go: running Assign 3a - First Assembler Program

Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000

Go: execution terminated with errors.
```

I am new to MIPS and assembly is very different compare to object oriented programming. How can I change my code so it doesn't throw any errors? I couldn't really find a good source or website in order to learn MIPS. Its either the book or people mostly. Let me know if you know a good source that I can go to.

Comment: _"I get alot of erros when I run the program"_. Then you should specify _exactly_ what those errors are in your question.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Just put my errors

Comment: Well, just like the assembler is telling you, you've got multiple labels with the same name. Each of them needs to have a different name. Though you don't really need to put a label in front of every data declaration unless you need to get the address of that particular data somewhere in your code.

Comment: I removed the duplicated labels and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Oh, the error is after your run it you mean? I mean, program runs fine (shows the sum of all integers) but when finished, shows the error.

Comment: Now you should single step the code in the simulator and see where it goes wrong. One suspicious thing is `j findMin3` which should probably be `jal findMin3` because that is a subroutine.

Comment: @Jester Yes, that's definitely the problem.